# searching web process / flow chart library like in sapui5

Tags: javascript, charts, flowchart

I'm searching a javascript chart library, which is similar like:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ProcessFlow

sadly, this chart isn't available in the free openui5 version.

Additional to show processes in a flow, the process chart library should have a possibility to set a status (which is e.g. visible by color or something else).

I appreciate every help.
BR

Comment: What features from it are you looking for, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided for mermaidjs.
Actually one of my (not mentioned) requirements were JSON as describing language to render the chart. But I can also use their own syntax with a template engine like pebble. mermaidjs has almost all the features I was looking for.